# How to redirect one controller to another controller based on condition using spring4?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to redirect the control from one controller to another.But when I browsed I found send redirect...I am not sure how much this 'll be effetive...please suggest me

Comment: What do you mean by *"I am not sure how much this 'll be effe[c]tive"*? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(ModelMap model) {

    ... ...
    do something
    ... ...

    return "getpage";
}

@RequestMapping(value="post", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(ModelMap model) {

    ... ...
    do something
    ... ...

    return "redirect:/get";
}
```